# How to build Tensorflow Lite 1 on Yocto 2.4 Rocko on Quectel SC20

Tags: tensorflow-lite, qualcomm, yocto-recipe, quectel, yocto-layer

I use `Quectel SC20 (Qualcomm MSM8909 SoC)` with `Yocto Rocko 2.4` and `Bitbake 1.36` and try to install `Tensorflow Lite v1.x` on it.

Unfortunately, the [Yocto layer for TensorFlow Lite interpreter with Python / C++.](https://github.com/NobuoTsukamoto/meta-tensorflow-lite) does not support Rocko because it is EOL. This is all I have found for the TensorFlow Lite Yocto layer.

Do you have any recommendations to build Tensorflow Lite 1 on Yocto 2.4 Rocko on Quectel SC20?